# Spring selectively use implementation instead of interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Can't find a definitive answer so asking here - Is it possible to turn on CGLIB proxying for only one bean? The scenario is following - I have a class which is autowired and don't implement any interfaces, now I want to add an interface which would cover a small subset of it methods. Is it possible to keep proxying *only this* class using CGLIB w/o impacting Spring's default behavior (JDK dynamic proxies are preferred)? 
I'm using java-based configuration.

Comment: Why? If you need to program to the concrete instance whilst using an interface you are doing it wrong or at least your interface doesn't match the intend you are trying to express.

Comment: @M.Deinum I know, I know, thanks a lot. Do you know the answer to the question?

Comment: The answer is basically not to do that and have a proper interface and use that. If you only want this single instance proxied you need to manually create the proxy or enable class based proxying and then it will be used for everything.

Comment: @M.Deinum ok, using the correct terms the "don't do that" would be an advice and "not possible unless you create the proxy manually" is the answer :). Regarding the part with manual proxying - I'd really appreciate if you could share the link to some example. Just wanna know how it looks like.

Comment: to downvoter - pls, try read first what this small triangular button says :). unless you specify what the problem is you downvoting pretty pointless

Comment: Instead of directly returning your object you would use the `ProxyFactory` to create a proxy and set the `proxyTargetClass` property to `true` before doing so. Spring will detect the fact that it already is a proxy and register additional advices with the pre-created proxy. Drawback here is you need to  know the internals of Spring to make this work (and understand) so you might want to put a lot of documentation on it on why this is done.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum, it's a useful one. I think I will not go so far at this point - will change the interface to superclass by now and probably refactor it later if we hit some meaningful downsides of this approach. Could you copy your comment as the answer so I could accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There (currently) is not any support out-of-the-box to enable class based proxies for a single class. Instead you would have to create the proxy yourself. The drawback of this is that you would need some intimate knowledge on how Spring works (which I happen to have :) ).

You should/could use the `ProxyFactory` or `ProxyFactoryBean` to create a class based proxy for your given class. Your `@Bean` method would return the proxy instead of the actual class. Spring is then clever enough (at least it should) to detect that it already is proxy and instead of proxying it again it should add the advices to the already created proxy. To make this work without destroying auto wiring and all other nice things Spring gives you, you probably want to create a specific `BeanPostProcessor` that handles this.

```
public YourBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    public  Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        if (bean instanceof YourBean) {
            ProxyFactory factory = new ProxyFactory(bean);
            factory.setProxyTargetClass(true);
            return factory.getProxy();
        }
        return bean;
    }

    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Register this as a bean as you normally would do with a `BeanPostProcessor`.

```
@Bean
public static YourBeanPostProcessor yourBeanPostProcessor() {
    return new YourBeanPostProcessor();
}
```

Now you have a pre-created class-based proxy which should be detected and used by Spring.